# Would the `install` command help me merge a build directory into the root filesystem?

Tags: software-installation, file-copy

I have successfully built a project from source and would like to use it. For various reasons I do not have a simple `make install` command available but I noticed that the sufficient portion of the build process that *did* succeed has already gathered up all the stuff I need into an `install/` subdirectory:

```
~/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/install
└── usr
    └── local
        ├── bin
        │   ├── msp430-elf-addr2line
        │   ├── msp430-elf-ar
        │   ├── msp430-elf-as
        │   ├── msp430-elf-c++
        …   …   …
```

Now I could just add `~/msp430-gcc-9.3.1.11-source-full/install/usr/local/bin` to my `PATH` and be done, but since this is basically a VM-like host dedicated to this specific project I'd kind of like to just actually install what I've built system-wide.

I thought maybe the old Unix `install` command might be appropriate for this task, but afaict it doesn't have any built-in recursive option and isn't much fancier than doing `cp`+`chmod` on individual files.

Is there an elegant way to "properly" merge this build subtree into my root filesystem, or should I just `rsync` this "install" folder to `/` and call it good?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing magical about the install command. Unlike what the intro of `man install` suggests, it really just copies the files (with options to also chown, chmod, strip, mkdir...) -- so you may just as well use rsync or cp.
Either way you need to ensure proper ownership and permissions.

Comment: Agree.  'install' is cp+chmod+chown+chgrp in if you pull the GNU source code you'll see all the utiliies are just fascades over the same underlying function library.   I'm not a fan of rsync (way too much fluff) but it's a solid choice.